# Spring and Scala - Function1 constructor-arg

Tags: spring, scala

I'm wrestling with creating a bean using a Twitter Scala class. Its constructor arguments aren't simple types, and instead are Scala Function1 types. How can I go about creating it?

```
<bean id="permissivePolicy" class="com.twitter.finagle.http.filter.Cors.Policy">
</bean>
```

This class's constructor arguments are:

```
case class Policy(
  allowsOrigin: String => Option[String],
  allowsMethods: String => Option[Seq[String]],
  allowsHeaders: Seq[String] => Option[Seq[String]],
  exposedHeaders: Seq[String] = Nil,
  supportsCredentials: Boolean = false,
  maxAge: Option[Duration] = None
)
```

Which means, in the Spring bean, I need to pass constructor-args of types:

```
1. allowsOrigin - Function1<String, Option<String>>
2. allowsMethods - Function1<String, Option<Seq<String>>>
3. allowsHeaders - Function1<Seq<String>, Option<Seq<String>>>
4. exposedHeaders - Seq<String>
5. supportsCredentials - boolean
6. maxAge - Option<Duration>
```

I'm not well-versed in Scala, so I'm not sure how to go about creating this bean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted this out. I first had to add the scala-util to the application.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:scala-util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/scala/util"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/scala/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/scala/util/scala-util.xsd">
```

I also needed to create an Scala implementation of the Function1 trait (which is basically just an interface):

```
    package com.test.util

    class Function1Impl extends Function1[String, Option[String]] {
      override def apply(v1: String): Option[String] = Some("")
    }
```

Now, back in application.xml, I created the necessary Beans to match the constructor args and created the permissivePolicy beans referencing them:

```
      <bean id="scalaOptionBean" class="scala.Some">
        <constructor-arg value="" />
      </bean>
      <bean id="function1Bean" class="com.test.util.Function1Impl" />
      <scala-util:seq id="scalaSeqBean" />

      <bean id="permissivePolicy" class="com.twitter.finagle.http.filter.Cors.Policy">
        <constructor-arg ref="function1Bean" />
        <constructor-arg ref="function1Bean" />
        <constructor-arg ref="function1Bean" />
        <constructor-arg ref="scalaSeqBean" />
        <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true" />
        <constructor-arg ref="scalaOptionBean" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="httpFilter"
            class="com.twitter.finagle.http.filter.Cors.HttpFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="permissivePolicy" />
      </bean>
```

That gave me a Policy object with essentially empty constructor-arguments of the right type. If I want to populate them at some point, just need to either change the Function1Impl or adjust the values in application.xml.